# How to create multiple content_tags using safe_concat ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, string-concatenation, content-tag

I'm trying to concatenate multiple tags using content_tag and safe_concat, something like:

```
content_tag(:select, multiple: "multiple", :name => "contact[resources]") do
    content_tag(:optgroup, label: "LABEL", id: "some-id") do 
      safe_concat(
        if condition1
          (content_tag(:option, value: "val1") { "Val1" } )
        end
        if condition2
          (content_tag(:option, value: "val2") { "Val2" } )
        end              
      )
    end                
  end
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_if, expecting ')' 
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap every single output in `safe_concat`, like

```
content_tag(:select, multiple: "multiple", :name => "contact[resources]") do
  content_tag(:optgroup, label: "LABEL", id: "some-id") do 
    if condition1
      safe_concat(content_tag(:option, value: "val1") { "Val1" } )
    end
    if condition2
      safe_concat(content_tag(:option, value: "val2") { "Val2" } )
    end              
  end                
end
```